# subtract debit and credit column

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I wrote following view in sql

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Accounting.TopicA.CodeA, SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit) AS DEB, SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit) AS CRED, 
                      Accounting.TopicA.Description
FROM         Accounting.TopicA INNER JOIN
                      Accounting.DocumentDetail ON Accounting.TopicA.CodeA = SUBSTRING(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Topic, 1, 2)
GROUP BY Accounting.TopicA.CodeA, Accounting.TopicA.Description
ORDER BY Accounting.TopicA.CodeA
```

And the result is

```
codea |Description | DEB | CRED |
1      Bank        | 100 | 30   |
2      Cash        | 40  | 70   |
.
.
.
```

now i need to add two more column to subtract DEB and CRED ,like when subtraction is positive then put the result in POS column else NEG column like below

```
codea |Description | DEB | CRED |  NEG | POS |
1      Bank        | 100 | 30   | 70   | 0   |
2      Cash        | 40  | 70   | 0    | 30  |
.
.
.
```

Comment: What error did you get and what have you tried?

Comment: I can make the first result BUT I need to make the second result also and the first one is working now but no idea about second one @AdrianThompsonPhillips

Comment: Please note that `TOP (100) PERCENT` - `ORDER BY` construct is completely useless. It will not have effect when you actually select from view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Accounting.TopicA.CodeA,
SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit) AS DEB,
SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit) AS CRED,
CASE WHEN SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit) - SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit) < 0
THEN SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit) - SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit)
ELSE 0 END AS NEG,
CASE WHEN SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit) - SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit) > 0
THEN SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit) - SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit)
ELSE 0 AS POS,
Accounting.TopicA.Description
FROM Accounting.TopicA 
INNER JOIN Accounting.DocumentDetail 
ON Accounting.TopicA.CodeA = SUBSTRING(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Topic, 1, 2)
GROUP BY Accounting.TopicA.CodeA, Accounting.TopicA.Description
ORDER BY Accounting.TopicA.CodeA
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I thought too. Good job!

Comment: Side question, will the sum of the column be calculated every time you do `SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit)` or does the value get calculated once and the sql engine re-uses the result every time you use that value?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That would be up to the DB engine, but I would be *very* surprised if it recalculated it.  It's generally smart enough to do stuff like that.  That said, there are [other solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17325665/1159478) that can avoid repeating it for code-clarity more than anything else.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It's calculated only once.

Answer (score 0):

I have the idea to use a CASE statement to do this.

Here's a link to sql server's CASE documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx 
I'm just guessing you're using sql server as the question is stamped C#, though it should be compatible with mysql, oracle,... too.

The idea is to use this CASE to know when to put 0 either in the NEG or POS column, and where to put the actual result.

Note: Do you really have to have the NEG and POS columns? Don't you just want to create a "result" column instead?

Answer (score 0):

For the negative column you can use:

```
ABS(Min(0, theSubtraction))
```

for the positive column you can use:

```
Max(0, theSubtraction)
```